# Open specific file using key when using vscode / vim

Tags: visual-studio-code

I often work in a specific file and would like to have that file opened when pressing a shortcut. I tried several combinations but seem to hit a wall..

```
    // file settings.json

    "vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {
            "before": ["leader","t"],
            "commands": [ 
                "vscode.open"
            ],
            "args": "notes/todo.md"
        }
    ]
```

Any hint on how i can get this working? When executing the above code i get a illegal argument 'resource'

Answer (score 0):

Using normal vim keywords solves the problem.

```
        {
            "before": [
                "leader", "t"
            ],
            "commands": [
                ":edit file:///notes/todo.md"
            ]
        }
```